# General relativity in three spacetime dimensions and maximally symmetric spacetimes

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, symmetry, spacetime-dimensions, cosmological-constant

Starting from Einstein's equations in $n$ spacetime dimensions with cosmological constant $\Lambda$:
$$R_{\mu\nu}+\left(\Lambda-\frac{R}{2}\right)g_{\mu\nu}=0,$$
one can that, by contracting both sides by $g^{\mu\nu}$, isolating $R$, we get $R = \frac{2n}{n-2}\Lambda$ so, substituting in the original equation, we get
$$R_{\mu\nu}=\frac{2}{n-2}\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$$
which is equivalent to Einstein's equations. Now, if $n=3$, the Weyl tensor vanishes so the Riemann tensor is given by
$$R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = \Lambda(g_{\alpha\mu}g_{\beta\nu}-g_{\alpha\nu}g_{\beta\mu}),$$
which is the Riemann tensor of maximally symmetric spacetimes.

My problem is the following:

I read that maximally symmetric spacetimes that are connected are only of three types : de Sitter spacetime if $\Lambda>0$, Minkowski spacetime if $\Lambda=0$ and anti-de Sitter spacetime if $\Lambda<0$. But a more rigorous statement is to say that maximally symmetric spacetimes are only locally isometric (or diffeomorphic?) to those, no? So there are actually a lot of maximally symmetric spacetimes.

If there are just those three cases, what about BTZ spacetime ? It is not one of the three, is it?

So my questions really is: what are the properties of three-dimensional spacetimes exactly?